# Delete Records from SOLR by checking 2 fields in Node JS

Tags: node.js, solr, nosql

I am using SOLR as my database and I have to delete all the records from the database where (UUID: 'a7d37405-fd5b-44de-b4bc-e748e9353f5d' and name:'Murtaza'). I can delete it by using just 1 field but it does not allow me to delete using 2 where clauses. Is there any way to do this?

I am using this code:

```
var objQuery = {UUID:'a7d37405-fd5b-44de-b4bc-e748e9353f5d'}

client.delete(objQuery, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
       console.log(err);
       return;
    }
    client.softCommit();
    callback(result.responseHeader);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

The inbuilt `delete` function only allows the 1 field+value as an argument, but you could use the `deleteByQuery` option:

http://lbdremy.github.io/solr-node-client/code/deleteByQuery.js.html

And make the query a conditional search for both fields:

```
var query = "UUID:'abcd-1234' AND name:Murtaza";
```

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot, man! I will add the complete code in the answer! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution finally! We have to use deleteByQuery function. The function code is:

```
var client =solr.createClient(options);

var query = 'UUID:814caeda-5ef1-4ecf-8260-222060d9907c AND toolId:mytoolID';


client.deleteByQuery(query,function(err,obj){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        client.softCommit();
        callback(obj.responseHeader);;
    }
 });
```